# jsf ajax trigged after jquery validation function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf

I'm facing a problem within JSF ajax request and jQuery Event.

I'm using jQuery event to validate a form part like this :

```
    jQuery(".btnNextStep").live("click", function(e) {
    var error = !validate(id);
            ...
    return error;
```

and under the same button, I have an Ajax event :

```
<h:commandButton type="button" value="Etape suivante" class="btn btn-large btn-primary btnNextStep" id="btnFormIdentite">
<f:ajax execute="identite" render="@none" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The problem is that the ajax request is submited even if jQuery event return false !

how can I do so that the request is sent after the jquery validation function ?

I have tried the onEvent on `f:ajax` but it seem that it's not possible to call a function inside of the jQuery namespace:

```
 (jQuery(document).ready( function() {...)
```

I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Use server side validation.

Comment: Also See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416695/jsf-ajax-request-is-not-fired-when-combined-with-js-client-side-validation

Answer (score 0):

Try define your validate function like this :

```
function vlidateNextStep() {
    var error = false;
    error = !validate(id);
            ...
    return error;
}
```

And use on click:

```
<h:commandButton type="button" value="Etape suivante" class="btn btn-large btn-primary btnNextStep" id="btnFormIdentite" onClick="return vlidateNextStep();">
    <f:ajax execute="identite" render="@none" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this, but the function vlidateNextStep need to be outside of the jquery namespace.

Comment: @user1823099 Try make the part you need in documentReady inside a function and call it in vlidateNextStep  which outside documentReady

Comment: I don't know how to call a fonction inside of namespace from outside... (function is undefined...)